# Should I use inheritance in this case?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to add this piece of code to a number of custom view controllers, some of which inherit from UITableViewController and other just from UIViewController:

```
self.backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 40, 40)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton.png"];
[self.backButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:self.backButton];
[self.backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)backButtonPressed{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

My question is: what is the best approach to have this piece of code available accross my multiple view controllers. Inheritance? If so, how can I have it in view controllers that inherit from different classes?

Comment: Do you have a navigation bar displaying? I see you're using a navigation controller. You're adding the button to the view when it should probably go in the navigation bar if it's displayed.

Comment: I'm hiding the navigation bar, that's why I need this button.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend towards inheritance with two subclasses (one for `UITableViewController` and one for `UIViewController`). It means copying the code once, but that's better than many times. Anything else gets a little messy (swizzling + categories of native classes).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by abstracting that code into a helper object. That way you're flexible about what kind of object (UIViewController, UITableViewController, anything else) wants to call it.

ButtonHelper.m might implement something like this:

```
-(UIButton *)backButtonForViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 40, 40)];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton.png"];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [viewController.view addSubview:backButton];
    [backButton addTarget:viewController action:@selector(backButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return backButton;
}
```

It could be a static method if you like those, or you could make an instance of ButtonHelper in your original class. Then the caller could say:

```
self.backButton = [ButtonHelper backButtonForViewController:self];
```

You could also pass in size metrics or images, if you like, instead of having hard coded strings or numbers.